# Cyrillic Encoding in Urllib Python 3.5

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib, anaconda

I'm using Python 3.5 with Anaconda 2.4.0 and trying to parse site using urllib and BeautifulSoup. I wrote a simple code but it displays wrong encoding of cyrillic symbols (html page in windows-1251 encoding) so displays something like that:

`[<td align="center" widh="30"><a href="/registration/"><img alt="\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f" border="0" src="/images/pers.png"/></a></td>]` and so on

I've tried a lot ways to encode this but all of them failed. Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table')


    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        cols=row.find_all('td')
        print(str(cols).encode('utf-8'))


def main():
    parse(get_html('http://www.prof-volos.ru/hair/shampoo/damaged/sale/1/'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: see if the answer below will work for you.

Comment: shows error
[Decode error - output not utf-8]

Comment: Did you use the exact code below? Can you paste the full error? What Operating system are you using?

Comment: Yep.
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.9s], Win7

Comment: Interesting - my python2.7 version is working on OS X and the Python3 version works on Linux. I will see if I can find a Windows box. Do you have a Linux machine you can use to see if that will let your script run?

Comment: please take a look at my new solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me using python3.4:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')

    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        for col in row.find_all('td'):
            print(col.text)

def main():
    parse(get_html('http://www.prof-volos.ru/hair/shampoo/damaged/sale/1/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Why does this work?

I think you were decoding the Beautiful Soup resultSet list at once, instead of separating the tags from the text.

Beautiful Soup does **UnicodeDammit** which is detecting CP1251 and converting to UTF8 automatically.

I made 2 changes:

Use `html.parser` instead of `lxml` (I am not sure if this matters at all).

Print the text of each `col` instead of directly using the `row.find_all` result.

Answer (score 0):

If this answer works for the original poster, I am going to delete my other answer.  I now suspect there is an encoding interaction between the Python script (using UTF-8) and Windows (using some other encoding). Proposed solution: write output to a file.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    lines = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')

    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        for col in row.find_all('td'):
            lines.append(col.text)
    return(lines)

def main():
    url = 'http://www.prof-volos.ru/hair/shampoo/damaged/sale/1/'
    with open('ThisFileWillBeBlindlyOverwritten.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in parse(get_html(url)):
            f.write(u'{}'.format(line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```